# Match lines which don't start with a comment (after any number of tabs)

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I am using negative lookahead to find every line which does not start with a comment (only "//"), but before the "//" symbol there could be any number of tabs.

This is my regex (i am using notepad ++):

```
^\t*(?!//).*
```

Example: In this sample file:

```
                LineOfCode ...
                // Other Comment
                // Comments can contain every time of symbol, including "//", ".", etc.
                // /**
                    // Another comment ...
                // */
                Line Of Code ...
                    // .,.,-
```

only the first and seventh lines should match, but with my regex all of them match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^(?!\h*//).*
```

The `^(?!\h*//)` lookahead matches a line that starts with 0+ horizontal whitespaces and then `//`, and then the rest of the line is matched.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZmNMq7/1).

Use these options:

[image]